# Plot data on different graphs based on the name in column

Tags: r

That's how data looks like:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(Name = c("A0A0C4DGB6_SA", "P02768_SA", "P02768_NA", 
"P02768_pCA", "A0A0C4DGB6_HCl", "P02768_HCl"), Amount = c(19649731, 
3907585251.21, 2528424589.42, 2229394895.99, 1387044, 3988958499.98
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to plot (for example barplot) on separate graphs two different `Name` which can be found in first column. One name is `A0A0C4DGB6` and second is `P02768`. For first there are only 2 values to be plotted (_SA and _HCl) for second there are 4 values to be plotted (_NA, _SA, _pCA, _HCl). I would like to have them on separate plots and bars should be named using `NA`, `pCA`, etc.

The only problem is that is an example data set and for real data it will be up to 50 different `Name` and the number of bars may vary from 1 to 4, however I have no idea if scale will work ok for them. I will normalize data if necessary later on.

Can someone help me out ?

```
structure(list(Name = c("P02671_SA", "P02675_SA", "P02679_SA", 
                           "C9JC84_NA", "P02671_NA", "P02675_NA", "C9JC84_pCA", "P02671_pCA", 
                           "P02675_pCA", "P02671_HCl", "P02675_HCl", "P02679_HCl"), Amount = c(1043300765.29, 
                                                                                                      749196962.67, 532044057, 9072048, 404582165.53, 111330551, 158031861, 
                                                                                                      541025331.71, 156542044, 1550158695.6, 1232481015.74, 1432502461.83
                           )), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so?

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>%
  separate_wider_delim(Name, delim = "_", names = c("first", "second")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = second, y = Amount, fill = second)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_grid(~first) + #or facet_wrap for more col/row control
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

**image from the updated sample data**

```
mydata <- structure(list(Name = c("P02671_SA", "P02675_SA", "P02679_SA", 
                                  "C9JC84_NA", "P02671_NA", "P02675_NA", "C9JC84_pCA", "P02671_pCA", 
                                  "P02675_pCA", "P02671_HCl", "P02675_HCl", "P02679_HCl"), Amount = c(1043300765.29, 
                                                                                                      749196962.67, 532044057, 9072048, 404582165.53, 111330551, 158031861, 
                                                                                                      541025331.71, 156542044, 1550158695.6, 1232481015.74, 1432502461.83
                                  )), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")

library(tidyverse)
mydata %>%
  separate_wider_delim(Name, delim = "_", names = c("first", "second")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = second, y = Amount, fill = second)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_wrap(~first, ncol = 2) +
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

Comment: I got the error `could not find function "separate_wider_delim"` even tho I have loaded the respective package... It looks like I have not load any other package which could be "masking" it in current session, however maybe smth which was loaded globally ?

Comment: it is located in `tidyr`, part of the (in de code) loaded `tidyverse`. make sure you have the latest version of tidyr (I run 1.3.0). See: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_wider_delim.html

Comment: It works perfectly! Can you also show me how to do it for more than 2 different names ? I have edited the question with additional representative example. I was trying to use `facet_wrap` but failed badly.